# Variable inside regular expression php

Tags: php, regex, variables

I a stuck with regular expression and i need help.
So basically i want to do somethning like this:

```
$data = "hi";
$number = 4;

$reg = '/^[a-z"]{1,4}$/';


if(preg_match($reg,$data)) {
    echo 'Match';   
}else {
    echo 'No match';
}
```

But i want to use variable

```
$reg = '/^[a-z"]{1, variable here }$/';
```

I have tried:

```
$reg = '/^[a-z"]{1, '. $number .'}$/';

$reg = "/^[a-z\"]{1, $number}$/";
```

But not getting right result.

Tnx for help

Comment: In the first example, you are using single quotes which prevents PHP from parsing your variable as a variable.

Comment: @AlexW - it doesn't matter which quotes did he use, since he split the string to two parts and add `$number` via `.` operator

Comment: @Drecker I was referring to the example above that. Where he put `variable here`.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In the first example you have an extra space where you shouldn't have one.

Also, **you should always quote such variable** as it may contain special characters recognized by regex.
You should have:

```
$reg = '/^[a-z"]{1,'. preg_quote($number) .'}$/';
```

then it would work just fine.

Comment: I had a problem with this where when I tried putting variables inside it, it doesn't work but when I put in the text from the variable to the correct location, it works quite find.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to use variables in regex is through the use of sprintf.

For example:

```
$nonWhiteSpace = "^\s";
$pattern = sprintf("/[%s]{1,10}/",$nonWhiteSpace);
var_dump($pattern); //gives you /[^\s]{1,10}/
```