# Make a regex match for all physical/chemical/biological units?

Tags: php, regex

I'm writing a PHP function to match all units in my content. 
For example:
I have "25 NaHCO3, 25 D-glucose, 11.6 sodium, 7 MgSO4, 3.1 sodium pyruvate, 2.5 KCl, 1.25 NaH2PO4, and 0.5 CaCl2" in my first phrase

and

"100 mg/kg, 4 kHz to 48 kHz, 40 rpm, 5 min, 26 cm, 95%CI, 16 yrs, 1.910 J mol-1 K-1, 50 cm3 min-1" and many.

Basic idea is to **capture all values coming with any sort of units** at the same time it **should not match randomly "any numbers followed by any words"**.

I could build a static regex with all sorts of units dumped into it like

```
/((?<![\,\-\.\<\=\>\da-z])[\-\+]?\d+(?:[\.\,\/](?=\d)\d+%?)*%?)(?![\-])([\s\x{00A0}\-]*(?:[a-z]{2,}(?:\/?[a-z\-])*(?=[\s\,\.\;\)])|[a-z](?=[\.\,\;]?\s)|A m-[0-9]|C m-[0-9]|F m-1|Gy s-1|H m-1|J K-1( mol-1)?|J kg-1( K-1)?|k?J mol-1( K-1)?|J m-3|N m|N s|Pa|Pa s|V m-1|W|W m-1 K-1|W m-2|W m-2 sr-1|W sr-1|cd sr|mol s-1|kat m-3|kg m s-1|kg m2|kg m2 s-1|kg[\s\/]m-?2|kg m-3|kg\/kg|kg|ci|m[\/]s|m s-[0-9]|[cm]?m-?[0-9](?: (?:k?g|min)-?[0-9])?|mol m-?[0-9]?(?: s-?[0-9])?|rad(?: s-?[0-9])|sr|u\/c|[\x{00B0}\x{00BA}o][FC]|K|\x{00C5}))(?![a-z0-9])/ui
```

with which i could capture many, but the pain is i have to add all units in my regex to do so and even after adding many units i could miss many units.

Is there any other option to build a regex with dynamic value?

Comment: Could you please clarify what values should (or shouldn't) be matched in each of your examples?

Comment: Values will be in numbers combination of either decimal or fraction (33, 4.5 or 66/34)

Comment: Sorry, let me be clearer -- could you please provide the **actual values** that you want to me matched, in the **given examples**. My interpretation is that in the first example, you want *nothing* to be matched; whereas in the second example, you want `"100"`, `"4"`, `"48"`, ... to be matched. Is that right?

Comment: Im my first example i want "25", "25", "11.6", "7", "3.1", "2.5" and in the second as you said it is "100", "4", "48"

Comment: And, what characters exactly should be matched? Digits are obviously needed, as are `"-"` (and `"+"`?) signs and `"."`.  Now you mention `"/"` characters, which are not in your example, so what else is there?... `"%"` characters? `"£"`, `"$"` and `"€"` characters? Brackets(`"(1+2)/3"`)? Commas (`"12,345"`)? Scientific notation (`"1.23e7"`)? I can't be much help without a more well defined question.

Comment: Sorry for not giving enough examples, values may be covered with `(2/3%)`, `7.5`, `10.5-23.4` and currenies will not be a part of values

Comment: Why don't you just capture all numbers followed by a space and the "word" that follows and then make a separate test for each match if the "word" fits your units-rules? This way you can get rid of the units in your regex.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/hG5pS4/3 this together with some more logic in PHP this will result in better readability of your code and less convoluted regex.

Comment: also check out this answer for the use of variables in regex pattern in PHP http://stackoverflow.com/a/25814103/6018688

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step is to decompose the pattern into subpatterns, which is especially meaningful in your case. The building blocks should be:

- the base units: J, K, s, min, yrs, ...
- a list of possible prefixes: f, p, n, μ, m, c, d, D, k, M, G, T, P, ...
- a list of characters than can be used to form derived units: ., *, /, ^, (, ), ...

Here is a start of solution

units: `(([PTGMkDdcmμnpf]?(mol|min|yrs|Hz|rpm|s|K|J|m|g)[\/\^\(\-\+\)0-9]*\s?)+)`
units preceded by a value only: `[\+\-]?\d*\.?\d*e?[\+\-]?\d*\s?(([PTGMkDdcmμnpf]?(%|mol|min|yrs|Hz|rpm|s|K|J|m|g)[\/\^\(\-\+\)0-9]*\s?)+)`

The first should parse only the units, the second parse the units and the value, ignoring numbers which are not followed by units and units which are not preceded by a value.

And [an example of it at work on your example](https://regex101.com/r/IDQi8a/2).
I added a few more tricky examples which you might need to account for.

However, bear in mind that this does not check the consistency of the unit.

You might want to have a look at how this problem was solved by [GNU Units](https://www.gnu.org/software/units/).

It provides unit conversion and has a *very* extensive list of units (including currencies, American system and miscellaneous units I have never seen elsewhere). In the source, there is a file "parse.y" that takes care of recognizing the unit.

I suppose you could inspire yourself from this or at least benefit from an already established database of units.

Update: thanks to Nahan Tuggy for the corrections. [Here](https://regex101.com/r/IDQi8a/3) is also an updated version with even trickier examples.